# Select Option Doesn't Set on Button Click with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried following a couple of answers with no success. I am trying to get the select box to go back to the "Please Select One Option" when the Add Exercise button is clicked. I got it to work in a simple scenario like this:

```
        <div id="retro_add_exercises">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <div class="select-wrapper initialized">
                <select class="initialized"  id="exercise_category">
                  <option value="0" disabled="" selected="">Please Select One</option>
                  <option value="1">Cardio</option>
                  <option value="2">Weight Lifting</option>
                  <option value="3">Stretching</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- CARDIO SELECT FIELD -->
          <div class="row" id="select_cardio">
            <form method="POST" id="cardio_form">
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" id="add_exercise_from_cardio" type="submit" name="action" value="ADD">Add Exercise from cardio</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#add_exercise_from_cardio').click(function() {
        $('#exercise_category').val('0').change();
    });
});
</script>
```

But in my main project, it isn't working when I have the row show and hide on button click too. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#retroactive_date_form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var date = $('#retroactive_date_picker');
        var exercise_date = date.val();
        if (exercise_date !== '') {
            var exercise_category;
            var weight_set_type;
            console.log(exercise_date);
            date.prop('disabled', true);
            $('#retroactive_date_submit').addClass('disabled');
            $('#retro_add_exercises').show();

            //Exercise Category Function
            $('#exercise_category').on('change', function() {
                exercise_category = $('#exercise_category').val();
                console.log(exercise_category);
                if (this.value === '1')
                {
                    $('#select_cardio').show();
                    $('#drop_or_reg_set_select_exercise').hide();
                    $('#super_set_select_exercises').hide();
                    $('#drop_and_regular_set_action_btn').hide();
                    $('#super_set_action_btn').hide();
                    $('#super_set_table_row').hide();
                    $('#drop_or_reg_set_table_row').hide();
                }
                else
                    $('#select_cardio').hide();
                if (this.value === '2')
                {
                    $('#select_weight').show()
                }
                else
                    $('#select_weight').hide();
                if (this.value === '3')
                {
                    $('#select_stretch_fields').show();
                    $('#select_cardio').hide();
                    $('#drop_or_reg_set_select_exercise').hide();
                    $('#super_set_select_exercises').hide();
                    $('#drop_and_regular_set_action_btn').hide();
                    $('#super_set_action_btn').hide();
                    $('#super_set_table_row').hide();
                    $('#select_weight').hide();
                    $('#drop_or_reg_set_table_row').hide();
                }
                else
                    $('#select_stretch_fields').hide();
                return exercise_category;
            });

            ///////////Cardio Training Functions///////////////
            //Selecting Cardio Exercise
            $('#cardio_exercise').on('change', function (e) {
                var cardio_exercise;
                cardio_exercise = $('#cardio_exercise').val();
                console.log(cardio_exercise);
            });

            //Adding Another Exercise After Done Adding Current Cardio Exercise
            $('#add_exercise_from_cardio').on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#exercise_category option[value="0"]').attr('selected', true);
                $('#select_cardio').hide();
                $('#drop_or_reg_set_select_exercise').hide();
                $('#super_set_select_exercises').hide();
                $('#drop_and_regular_set_action_btn').hide();
                $('#super_set_action_btn').hide();
                $('#super_set_table_row').hide();
                $('#drop_or_reg_set_table_row').hide();
            });

    //Error Handling If No Date is Selected Before Starting
        else {
            alert('Please select date')
        }
    });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <div id="retro_add_exercises" style="display:none">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                  <div class="select-wrapper initialized"><span class="caret">▼</span>
                    <select class="initialized"  id="exercise_category">
                      <option value="0" disabled="" selected="">Please Select One</option>
                      <option value="1">Cardio</option>
                      <option value="2">Weight Lifting</option>
                      <option value="3">Stretching</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <label>Choose Exercise Type</label>
                </div>
              </div>

              <!-- CARDIO SELECT FIELD -->
              <div class="row" style="display:none" id="select_cardio">
                <form method="POST" id="cardio_form">
                  <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <div class="select-wrapper initialized"><span class="caret">▼</span>
                      <select id="cardio_exercise" name="cardio_exercise" class="initialized">
                        <option value="0" disabled selected>Choose Cardio Exercise</option>
                        <option value="1">Jumping Jacks</option>
                        <option value="2">Jump Rope</option>
                        <option value="3">Precor</option>
                        <option value="4">Running (outside)</option>
                        <option value="5">Swimming</option>
                        <option value="6">Treadmill</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <input type="date" style="display:none" id="cardio_exercise_date" name="cardio_exercise_date">
                    <input placeholder="Duration (minutes)" name="cardio_duration" id="cardio_duration" type="number" class="validate">
                    <input placeholder="Distance (optional)" name="cardio_distance" id="cardio_distance" type="number" class="validate">
                    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" id="add_exercise_from_cardio" type="submit" name="action" value="ADD">Add Exercise</button>
                    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" id="finish_tracking" type="submit" name="action" value="FINISH">Finish Workout</button>
                    <label for="cardio_exercise">Choose Exercise</label>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
```

Comment: When you execute your code, you get a syntax error around one of your `if` statements.

Comment: You're missing the `}` for the first `if` statement, which goes before the last `else`.

Comment: I fixed that and tried to run your code, but I don't see anything. You have `style="display: none;"` on the whole thing.

Comment: I just uploaded it to a server to make things easier. christianlowe.com/trusique/html-custom/custom-folder/retroactively.html

Answer (score 0):

The [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2) dictates that since jQuery 1.6, attr will not update the dynamic state of a DOM element. In addition, it appears your select is disabled after being selected. Try:

```
$('#exercise_category option[value="0"]').prop('disabled', false);
$('#exercise_category option[value="0"]').prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. Here. I put it up on a server so you can take a look. http://christianlowe.com/trusique/html-custom/custom-folder/retroactively.html

Comment: @ChristianLowe I edited my answer to include first setting the disabled state to false. I believe it's not being selected because it gets disabled after selecting another option.

Comment: I tried that and still didn't work. Even tried removing the entire disabled attribute in the html to see if that was the cause, and with it removed I still don't get the desired result.

Comment: I tried that and still didn't work. Even tried removing the entire disabled attribute in the html to see if that was the cause, and with it removed I still don't get the desired result.

@Jamie I rebuilt the page going one piece at a time and figured out that something happens when the materialize.css file is applied to the html document. Other than that it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better and more efficient way to solve it, but I figured it out. I wrapped the select option in form wrappers and gave the form an ID. Then on the button click I triggered reset of the form using

```
$('#button_id').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#form_id').trigger('reset');
});
```

Although I'm sure there is a better way, this method worked for me and hopefully it works for someone else too.